# Check the data before updating in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use `findAndModify`, and it's works.

This is my Schema

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id               : ObjectId,
    username          : String,
}, {
    safe              : true
});
```

If I insert `username : 100`, my `username` in `Schema` change in `Double`.

Can i check the elements before update, and update only if `username` is `String`?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Why would you allow `username:100`? Why don't you ensure it `username:"100"`? How is your question related to mongodb?

Comment: If I get a value of 100 my Schema should not be updated.
Can I check the value before update?? can check if it's a string instead int? are there functions in mongoDb ?

Comment: Why don't you simply do that in your code? How could a **schemaless** database do that? I still don't see how this could change your schema, but it might insert a document that doesn't match your schema. To avoid that, make sure your objects always have the correct type. Read up on javascript type conversion, `instanceof` and the likes to learn how to do that in JS.

Comment: the question was. I have to use validations using js or there are functions that can help me with MongoDB...thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't be fooled by Mongoose, which is merely a 'helper' (though my feeling is it mostly adds confusion).

It's important to understand MongoDB by itself. MongoDB has no schema. You don't even need to *declare* a collection before using it, e.g. on a newly started mongodb, first command ever: `db.bla.insert({"Name":"john"});` just works. Then, do `db.bla.insert({"xf":1456});` also works, even though it is *completely different* from the first document.

Hence, MongoDB can't validate your object according to some kind of schema, and it doesn't have to. The question is whether your code can cope with that, or not. In most cases, it makes sense to have a strict schema. Enforcing the schema must be done by your application code, though I believe [Mongoose offers a helper, `doc.validate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validate) for this.